# WSO2 Authentication, adding/modifing timeout to the RememberMe cookie

Tags: web-services, authentication, wso2

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0 for user authentication.

When using the AuthenticationAdmin, I am able to use the loginWithRememberMeOption to retrieve a 'RememberMe' cookie, for instance:
admin-b55cdc95-a27e-4e3e-9906-76c18b8437c5

I see in the SOAP response that the cookie has a maxAge of 604800. Does this mean that the RememberMe cookie will be unvalidated after 604800ms / 10 mins?

I tried checking the validity of the cookie after 10 minutes by using the loginwithRememberMeCookie operation. But also after 10 minutes, the result was 'true', indicating that the user was still logged in.

Is it possible to add or modify a timeout, so that the session becomes inactive? If so, where can I modify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RememberMe cookie time is in seconds. So, 604800 seconds mean 7 days.

AFAIK, this value cannot be modified.

Session will time out after the session expiry time. You can change the session time out value. But you can still login with remember me cookie.

Comment: Ok. With the JSESSIONID there was the possibility to invalidate the session with the logout service. Say that I want to manually logout the user that has obtained a 'rememberMeCookie'. Is there a similar possibility for this case?